# Can I disable animation when use ionic modal?

Tags: animation, modal-dialog, ionic-framework

I want to remove the animation when open or close the modal. Can I do it?

```
$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/login.html', {
  scope: $scope,
  hardwareBackButtonClose: false,
  animation: null
})
```

I try to use null value but it not working for me.

Comment: what if you don't write animation at all ?

Comment: Seem it set to default value `animation: 'slide-in-up'` @mudasserajaz

Comment: here is a workaround which work for me. set this value and see `animation: 'slide-in-right' ` don't know why, but this animation does not work, resulting modal without animation.

Answer (score 4):

'none' is the built in way to disable the animation:

`$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/modal.html', {
  animation: 'none'
})`

This should be written somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

I used similar approach and seems to work:

`#login-modal{
  transform:none !important;
}`

Comment: Thank for your answer. :)

Comment: Solution worked in normal browser but not in Android, added webkit:

 #login-modal{
  transform:none !important;
   -webkit-transform:none !important;
 }

Answer (score 0):

I don't think ionic supports a value for animation that will disable the animation all together.  As far as I am aware, the only animations that Ionic supports are the ones listed here. https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/scss/_animations.scss

If this is true, I would say the easiest solution to getting somewhere without any animation is to set up a new state and link to that state through ui-sref and set the animation equal to none.

Comment: Yes, I think so. Thank for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `animation: 'no-animation'`  to disable transition but fade still work.

Edit #1:

maybe it cannot find class `no-animation`. not a good idea.

Edit #2:

Use

```
#login-modal{
   transform:none !important;
}
```

to disable it.